# Perl get md5 hash of a fetched file

Tags: perl, download, md5

I'm trying to create a hash of a file that i have downloaded using the module [File::Fetch](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/File-Fetch/File/Fetch.pm.html). I'm trying to store the downloaded file name and its hash in the database as a record. However, none of the methods of File::Fetch objects provide the downloaded file. Is there any way to download the file into a variable in order to create a hash of it?

Here is a snippet of my code,

```
eval{
    $uri_handle = File::Fetch->new(uri => $nurl) or die "Could'nt create fetch object\n";
    $getfile = $uri_handle ->output_file or die "There is no file to be fetched\n";
    my $dir_handle = $uri_handle->fetch( to => $dir2 ) or die "Couldn't fetch file: $uri_handle->error\n";
    # print "$getfile was successfully saved to $dir\n";
};
if ($@){
        print "\n There is no file at $url\n\n";            
}else{              
    my $file_data_handle = DBI->connect($database_connection_string,$database_user,$database_pass) or die "Couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr\n";
    my $file_statement_handle = $file_data_handle->prepare('insert into files (filename,filehash,sourceurl,originalurl) VALUES ($getfile,$filehash,$nurl,$url)') or die "Couldn't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr\n";
    $file_statement_handle->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr\n";
    $file_data_handle->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Not entirely related nitpick: proper exception handling does not use `if ($@)...` for error detection but the result of `eval` itself. A common idiom is something like `eval { ...; 1; } or do { print "Exception occured: $@\n"; };`

Comment: And according to the documentation you've linked to you can get to the locally stored file's name: `$ff->file The name of the remote file. For the local file name, the result of $ff->output_file will be used.`

Comment: Actually i was making use of any error that code within eval probably throws to be the result of no file being available at the particular url, then just skipping the grab entirely. On the other hand, if there was a file downloaded, i wanted to grab the hash of it, but there file fetch doesnt hold the file, it sends it directly to a folder specified by my variable `$dir2`

Comment: But `$url_handle` should hold that file's name, so just use that name, open the local file and read its content.

Comment: Okay, i shall try that approach first . Thanks

Comment: i just realized, if i use readdir to open the folder and get the file, would i be hashing the name or the file itself.

Comment: If you have a different/new/additional question the please post it as a new question along with code to show what you've tried. `readdir` returns file names, what you do with them is up to you, and I don't read minds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It writes the result to disk directly. Use LWP instead.

```
use Digest::MD5    qw( md5_hex );
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->get($url);
die $response->status_line if !$response->is_success;
my $file = $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' );
my $md5_hex = md5_hex($file);
```

Comment: Replace `die` with `next` and you don't need an `eval`.